# Managing Multiple UItextFields

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tags, uitextfield

Novice coder and I'm stuck. I have 2 `UITextField` on my Viewcontroller that I want passed to a `UITableView` when "save" is tapped.  I've set both textFields to delegate.self, the problem is that the data entered in the textfields only shows up on the UITableView IF I remove 1 of the UItextFields.

I'm thinking in order to use 2 (or more) UITextFields on the same VC I must need a way besides the outlets to differentiate between them. I've seen responses about tags but I don't understand.

```
import UIKit

class BudgetViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // Properties:
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateDisplay: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!


    var budget: Budget?

    // Date picker:
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    func setDate() {
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        dateDisplay.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    }

    // Navigation

    // This method lets you configure a view controller before it's presented
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {

            let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
            let date = dateDisplay.text ?? ""
            let amount = amountTextField.text ?? ""

    // set the budget to be passed to the Controller, this code configures the meal prperty with the appropriate values before the segue executes

            budget = Budget(date: date, name: name, amount: amount)     
        }
    }

    // Actions:
    @IBAction func datePickerChanger(sender: AnyObject) {
        setDate()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Handle the text field

        nameTextField.delegate = self
        amountTextField.delegate = self
    }
    // UITextFieldDelegate

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {


    }
}




import UIKit

class BudgetTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //Properties
    var budgets = [Budget]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadSampleBudgets()

    }

    func loadSampleBudgets() {

        let budget1 = Budget(date: "8/16/2016", name: "Eyebrows", amount: "15")!
        let budget2 = Budget(date: "8/28/2016", name: "Acme", amount: "59")!
        let budget3 = Budget(date: "9/10/2016", name: "Wildwood", amount: "199")!

        budgets += [budget1, budget2, budget3]
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection    section: Int) -> Int {

        return budgets.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "BudgetTableViewCell"

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier,     forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BudgetTableViewCell
        let budget = budgets[indexPath.row]

        cell.dateLabel.text = budget.date
        cell.nameLabel.text = budget.name
        cell.amountLabel.text = budget.amount
        return cell
    }

@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? BudgetViewController, budget = sourceViewController.budget {

//Add a new meal

    let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: budgets.count, inSection: 0)
    budgets.append(budget)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowanimation: .Bottom)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better what the problem is. How does it not work when you send the second text field? Is it crashing? Is it sending an empty string?

Comment: My storyboard has 2 textfields and a save button.  As written, the app won't add any of the data entered in either textfield to the tableview.  However once I deleted one and all of its components it works. So I'm assuming you can't have multiple textfields assigned as the delegate of the same view controller without assigning some sort of order or priority. @boidkan

Comment: And I can delete either textField and whatever is entered in the remaining textfield will pass to the tableview, there just can't be 2 text fields without something that I'm missing.  @boidkan

Comment: So you can have multiple text fields that have the same delegate you will just have to handle it in the delegate methods . You can do so by checking what textfield is being passed into the method like so:

    `func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
          if textField === nameTextField{

         }
    }`

The triple `===` checks to see if they are the exact same objects.

Comment: I would suggest trying to debug by checking the values of the text fields right before segueing. You have a bug somewhere and it's hard for us to know exactly where it is without having the project in front of us.

Comment: yaaaah! that worked @Boidkan amountTextField has to be entered first. Now I'm going to play around to figure out how to change their order without messing up something else.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Is your project on github or something so I can take a look?

Comment: @boidkan it's not but it's working now, thanks to you.  I'm just not sure why the amountTextfield is being called first.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your text fields outlets are properly linked to your storyboard. There should be a filled circle next to each IBOutlet. If you have both the code and storyboard open in XCode and hover your mouse over the circle next to each outlet, the text field should highlight on the storyboard.

If you copied and pasted the original name text field and changed it to the amount text field, it actually still might have a reference to the name outlet. You can check this by right clicking on the text field in the storyboard and see what outlets it refers to.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        nameTextField.delegate = self
        streetTextField.delegate = self
        cityTextField.delegate = self
        stateTextField.delegate = self
        countryTextField.delegate = self
        phoneTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == nameTextField {
            streetTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == streetTextField {
            cityTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == cityTextField {
            stateTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == stateTextField {
            countryTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == countryTextField {
            phoneTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        else if textField == phoneTextField {
            nameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
    }
```

This is some code I wrote to allow a user to fill in a form (pressing return to move from one field to the next), so you can definitely have multiple textFields with the same delegate.

Comment: No everything as far as the outlets are correct.  The function works properly and the data saves to the tableView as long as I delete one of the textfields and all of it's mentions.  I'm assuming I to give the textFields an order or priority.  I read this in the apple documentation but didn't understand how to include it. @One In a Million Apps